# Using Refs in a Dynamic Length Array for scrollIntoView

Tags: react-hooks

I am somewhat new to using useEffect and useRef.  What I'm trying to do is create a content management system that enables scrollIntoView for n number of page elements from a database for a single page scrolling app.

I'm not able to get it to work so I'm hoping for some assistance.

I've posted a simple test where I have a functional react component where section 2 works (clicking the button scrolls down to the page element.

But my goal is to take 'n' sections from a database and create 'n' number of refs to scroll down to 'n' number of sections.

I tries useRef, useEffect, etc but I'm stumped.  My code snippet shows a working example with manual ref declarations for Section 2 but Section 1 attempts to use a collection of Refs and that's not working

Here is a code example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/trusting-stallman-bsjj1?fontsize=14

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  let pageRef = useRef([
    React.createRef(),
    React.createRef()
  ]);


  const pageHomeRef = React.createRef();

  const scrollToRef = ref => ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  const scrollToPane = ref => scrollToRef(ref);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="menu">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            scrollToPane(pageRef[1]);
          }}
        >
          Scroll to Section 1
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => scrollToPane(pageHomeRef)}>
          Section 2
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="page" style={{ marginTop: "1500px", marginBottom: "1500px" }}>
        <div className="section1" ref={pageRef[1]}>
          Section 1
        </div>
        <div className="section2" ref={pageHomeRef}>
          Section 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I'd like to feed an array of page elements and have the refs dynamically change as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Little order the code - try it

You can use React.createRef() or useRef(null) in the array.

And make us many refs you want in array.

And even make map if you have a list (https://dev.to/ajsharp/-an-array-of-react-refs-pnf)
And you have other ways insted of refs.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const App = () => {
  let pageRef = [useRef(null),useRef(null)];
  const pageHomeRef = [React.createRef(),React.createRef()];

  const scrollToRef = ref => ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  const scrollToPane = num => scrollToRef(pageRef[num]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="menu">
        <button
          onClick={() => {scrollToPane(0)}}>Scroll to Section 1</button>
        <button onClick={() => scrollToPane(1)}>Section 2</button>
      </div>
      <div
        className="page"
        style={{ marginTop: "1500px", marginBottom: "1500px" }}
      >
        <div className="section1" ref={pageRef[0]}>
          Section 1
        </div>
        <div className="section2" ref={pageRef[1]}>
          Section 2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: `const pageHomeRef = [React.createRef(),React.createRef()];` . This line is the issue.  I won't know how many ref's I'm going to need.  Is it possible to map() these?

Comment: Yes, it is array, you can push more empty ref. and make for list by index the number to the ref. look at the link, you also can use an object and with the section name for key and new ref for value.

Comment: I used your example and got it working.  Thanks for the quick response